# Group objects in Laravel collection by consecutive identical column values

Tags: php, laravel, collections, grouping, contiguous

I need some help with a grouping algorithm. I have some objects in a Laravel collection, here are some sample data in JSON representation:

```json
[
  {
    "group": "WHITE",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "sequence": 1
  },
  {
    "group": "WHITE",
    "name": "John Doe Jr",
    "sequence": 2
  },
  {
    "group": "BLUE",
    "name": "John Doe Sr",
    "sequence": 3
  },
  {
    "group": "BLUE",
    "name": "John Doe Again",
    "sequence": 4
  },
  {
    "group": "RED",
    "name": "Mr John Doe",
    "sequence": 5
  },
  {
    "group": "RED",
    "name": "Ms Joahnna Doe",
    "sequence": 6
  },
  {
    "group": "BLUE",
    "name": "Dr Johnny Doe",
    "sequence": 7
  },
  {
    "group": "RED",
    "name": "Sir John Doe",
    "sequence": 8
  },
  {
    "group": "RED",
    "name": "Sir John Doe Senior",
    "sequence": 9
  },
  {
    "group": "WHITE",
    "name": "Ms John Doe",
    "sequence": 10
  }
]
```

I'd like to be able to grouping theese objects by their group name BUT keeping the sequence unaltered, and repeating keys where occurs twice or more, like this:

```json
{
    "WHITE": [
        { "name": "John Doe", "sequence": 1 },
        { "name": "John Doe Jr", "sequence": 2 }
    ],
    "BLUE": [
        { "name": "John Doe Sr", "sequence": 3 },
        { "name": "John Doe Again", "sequence": 4 }
    ],
    "RED": [
        { "name": "Mr John Doe", "sequence": 5 },
        { "name": "Ms Joahnna Doe", "sequence": 6 }
    ],
    "BLUE (second group)": [
        { "name": "Dr Johnny Doe", "sequence": 7 }
    ],
    "RED (second group)": [
        { "name": "Sir John Doe", "sequence": 8 },
        { "name": "Sir John Doe Senior", "sequence": 9 }
    ],
    "WHITE (second group)": [
        { "name": "Ms John Doe",  "sequence": 10 }
    ]
}
```

I've already found a way doing like so:
I iterate every object looking for occurrences in the previous ones where the sequence number is not consecutive, and I add a new `group_name` key to the objects alternating this name when the previous condition is satisfied (i.e. adding a count of the splits that I've found). As far as I can remember, pushing every occurrence in the original collection let me use a simple `$collection->groupBy('group_name')`

```php
foreach ($data as $stop) {
    $previous_stops_in_group = $stops
        ->where('group', $stop->group)

    $stop->group_name = $stop->group;
    $stop->splitted = false;
    if ($previous_stops_in_group->count() >0) {
        $last_sequence_in_group = $previous_stops_in_group->last()->sequence;
        if (($stop->sequence - $last_sequence_in_group) > 1) {
            $splittedroutes++;
            $stop->group_name = $stop->group . $splittedroutes;
            $stop->splitted = true;
        }
    }


    $last_splitted_group = $stops
        ->where('splitted',true)
        ->where('stop_group',$stop->stop_group)
        ->where('direction', $stop->direction)->last();
    if (!empty($last_splitted_group) && isset($last_splitted_group->group_name)) {
        $stop->group_name = $last_splitted_group->group_name;
    }
    $stops->push($stop);
}
```

Unfortunally I've wrote this *masterpiece* about 1 year ago, and now I can't figure out what is going on because this algorithm should be applied to hundreds of records and it doesn't work as intended.

I'd like to find a more intuitive solution, using an expressive syntax, maybe with collection's native methods, maybe a combination of `partition()` and `mergeRecursive()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be done better with collections, but here is my approach:

```
$items = [
  {
    "group": "WHITE",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "sequence": 1
  },
  // ...
  {
    "group": "WHITE",
    "name": "Ms John Doe",
    "sequence": 10
  }
];

$result = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (!isset($result[$item['group']])) $result[$item['group']] = [];
    $result[$item['group']][] = [
        'name' => $item['item'],
        'sequence' => $item['sequence'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: This simply doesn't solve the problem, is a simple group by equivalent.
The point here is trying to have different group keys where sequence number are not sequential but group name is the same, so the ordered sequence is preserved by splitting groups and moving objects with non sequential number in another group with the same name (or with an altered one)

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce()` (or cast to an array with `->toArray()` and use PHP's native `array_reduce()`) to iterate the objects in your collection.  Use a few `static` variables to assist with identifying changes in grouping values and to increment each group's counter.

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/E4))

```
var_export(
    $collection->reduce(
        function ($result, $obj) {
            static $previousGroup,
                   $groupKey,
                   $keyCounters = [];
            $group = $obj->group;
            unset($obj->group);
            $keyCounters[$group] ??= 0;
            if (!$previousGroup || $previousGroup !== "$group " . $keyCounters[$group]) {
                $groupKey = "$group " . (++$keyCounters[$group]);
                $previousGroup = $groupKey;
            }
            $result[$groupKey][] = $obj;
            return $result;
        }
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'WHITE 1' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'John Doe',
       'sequence' => 1,
    ),
    1 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'John Doe Jr',
       'sequence' => 2,
    ),
  ),
  'BLUE 1' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'John Doe Sr',
       'sequence' => 3,
    ),
    1 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'John Doe Again',
       'sequence' => 4,
    ),
  ),
  'RED 1' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'Mr John Doe',
       'sequence' => 5,
    ),
    1 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'Ms Joahnna Doe',
       'sequence' => 6,
    ),
  ),
  'BLUE 2' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'Dr Johnny Doe',
       'sequence' => 7,
    ),
  ),
  'RED 2' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'Sir John Doe',
       'sequence' => 8,
    ),
    1 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'Sir John Doe Senior',
       'sequence' => 9,
    ),
  ),
  'WHITE 2' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'name' => 'Ms John Doe',
       'sequence' => 10,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
collect($data)->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
  $count = count($carry[$item["group"]] ?? []);
  $groupName = $item["group"] . ($count > 1 ? " (group {$count})" : "");

  $carry[$groupName][] = array_diff_key($item, array_flip(["group"]));

  return $carry;
}, []);
```